# Git is not ignoring after adding it to .gitignore

Tags: git

I have a `git` repository with a `config.properties` by default where some user data has to be written. When I change the content, add `*.properties` to my `.gitignore` and then go for `git status`, it keeps appearing as modified content and would upload it. What can I do?

My `.gitignore` is listed below. I also tried to add the last line of `.gitignore` to `git global ignore` but it doesn't help:

```
 # .gitignore
/target/
/test-output/
.classpath
.project
*.properties
```

Comment: Git will track already staged files, you have to unstage it first.

Answer (score 4):

Be aware that if the file you are trying to ignore is already tracked, it won't be ignored.

Check the documentation:

> https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

Comment: Yes, this is a possible solution, already tested. The problem with this, is that when I do "git rm --cached *.properties" and then go back to git status, it says that the file is deleted, and whenever I do a push of all changes, it will delete the file from the repository, and I want to keep that file.

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you are trying to do. If you want to modify your file but you want git to ignore the changes: git update-index --assume-unchanged /dirTo/yourFile.

Comment: I guess that might be a solution for now. I try to explain. I have a repository with a config.properties with some properties, but some of those have to be personal (User and password, for example). So I want everyone to have access to that file, but I dont want to update it, so, if I do "git rm --cached" and add the file to the .gitignore, it will detect that the file has been deleted and you want to delete it, but I dont want to delete it from the repository, I dont know if I explained right... If you dont understand its ok, I guess that solution may fit by now. Thank you

Comment: Then, if the solution fits now,  please, mark the question as answered. Thank you.